# Basic Bayesian MCMC to estimate two parameters from binomial distributions given unknown number of trials

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo

This is a very basic question about Bayesian inference. I'm not grasping one or more fundamental concepts.

Let's say I have two observed outcomes, *X* and *Y*. I want to infer the probabilities (*px* and *py*, respectively) of each occurring given *X* and *Y*. I do not know *N*, the total number of trials. I'm assuming that *X* and *Y* are binomially distributed. How do I calculate the likelihood without *N*?

**What I ultimately want is to show the bivariate posterior distribution of *px* and *py* via MCMC. I do not care about estimating *N*--I just want to show the chain in the plane of *px* and *py*. No convergence necessary.**

---

*Clarification:*  *X* and *Y* are drawn from the same *N*: *X* ~Binom(*N*, *px*) and *Y* ~Binom(*N*, *py*). We have no other information about *px* or *py*, although I'll use a beta prior to start. Also assume that *X* and *Y* are independent.

Comment: Are X and Y both drawn from the same distibution $Bin(N, p)$? And do we have any information about $p$?

Comment: Good questions! Revised post to clarify.

Comment: And are you familiar with Python?

Comment: Not Python, but C++, Java, Javascript, etc. I am going to use Javascript for this. It might be best to use pseudocode here.

Comment: It seems to me like the problem is under-determined.  You're trying to guess 3 unknowns (px, py, and N) from 2 data points, with no additional information. I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: No such thing as undetermined in Bayesian analysis, we can only be certain our priors will be more influential.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Sure, but in this case, the likelihood surface will be almost entirely flat and the prior will dominate almost entirely.

Comment: I can see how it's underdetermined with respect to _px_ and _py_ separately, but I'm really going after _px_ / _py_, which should produce a banana plot. (This is, ironically, for a MCMC tutorial, and I've conceptually lost the thread of how to get this to work. Users will have the option of switching between beta and uniform priors.)

Comment: Actually, I take it back: the likelihood will only be flat for large N.  There's a *lot* of curvature near N == max(X, Y). I wouldn't trust inferences near that value much, though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Model and Pseudocode

So I did some analysis in Python, though I used the pyMC library which hides all the MCMC mathy stuff. I'll show you how I modeled it in semi-pseudocode, and the results.

I set my observed data as $X=5, Y=10$.

```
X = 5
Y = 10
```

I assumed that $N$ has a Poisson prior, with the Poisson's rate a $EXP(1)$. This is a pretty fair prior. Though I could have chosen some uniform distribution on some interval:

```
rate = Exponential( mu = 1 )
N = Poisson( rate = rate)
```

You mention beta priors on $pX$ and $pY$, so I coded:

```
pX = Beta(1,1) #equivalent to a uniform
pY = Beta(1,1)
```

And I combine it all:

```
observed = Binomial(n = N, p = [pX, pY], value = [X, Y] )
```

Then I perform the MCMC over 50000 samples, burned-in about half of that. Below are the plots I generated after MCMC.

### Interpretation:

Let's examine the first graph for $N$. The *N Trace* graph are the samples, in order, I generated from the posterior distribution. The *N acorr* graph is the auto-correlation between samples. Perhaps there is still too much auto-correlation, and I should burn-in more. Finally, *N-hist* is the histogram of posterior samples. It looks like the mean is 13. Notice too that no samples were drawn from below 10. This is a good sign, as that would be impossible given the data observed was 5 and 10.

Similar observations can be made for the $pX$ and $pY$ graphs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Different Prior on $N$

If we restrict $N$ to be a Poisson( 20 ) random variable (and remove the Exponential heirarchy), we get different results. This is an important consideration, and reveals that the prior can make a large difference. See the plots below. Note the time to convergence was much larger here too.

On the other hand, using a Poisson( 10 ) prior produced similar results to the Exp. rate prior.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I should note that I tried the same analysis with an uninformative prior on $N$ and got terrible results (chain did not converge to anything meaningful, and autocorrelations spiked).

Comment: This looks really good--thanks. I hadn't been able to figure out what to do with _N_, but using a Poisson prior with some realism (i.e., >max(_X_,_Y_)) and fitting it too makes sense... and makes it easy to see how I'll calculate the likelihood. :P I'm going to try coding this up in js tomorrow and will almost certainly accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 @Cam.Davidson.Pilon. This seems to have worked better than I expected. What happens if you give it a more reasonable prior like Poisson(10) or Poisson(20) that has more probability mass in the feasible region above 10?

Comment: With a prior of Poisson(10), the results look the same (and convergence is quick), not so with Poisson(20). See edit above.

Comment: This is great, especially the Poisson examples. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, the posterior is not as obvious as I thought. The point of the conjugate beta priors for px and py is to calculate the posterior directly from the Beta distribution. I don't understand exactly where the priors for N should enter. This might deserve a separate question--actually writing the code is revealing to me the true depths of my ignorance.

Comment: Well, we need to include $N$ somehow, as we do not know its value beforehand. The postierior looks like:
$P(px,py | X,Y ) \propto P(X | px, N)P(Y | py, N) P(px)P(py)P(N)$.

Comment: Bayesian methods are quite difficult in the details. The overall picture is easy: *Return a distribution of the parameter in question, given the data and prior*, but the small details like: *how to sample*, *what to do with samples*, *what do I need to calculate* and so on can be intimidating. It took me three straight days staring at a computer screen to finally break through ahha