# Elementary MCMC pseudocode

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, bayes

My aim relates to the project described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47190/basic-bayesian-mcmc-to-estimate-two-parameters-from-binomial-distributions-given), but I've tried to make this question self-contained.

I'm trying to write the MCMC pseudocode for the following inference problem:

> Given two observed independent outcomes $X$ and $Y$, what are the
>   posterior densities of probabilities $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ of obtaining $X$ and $Y$, assuming $X$ ~
>   $\text {Bin}(N, p_{x})$ and $Y$ ~ $\text{Bin}(N, p_{y})$? We do not
>   know or observe $N$. We have priors for $N$, $p_{x}$, and $p_{y}$. We will assume
>   that $N$ ~ $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, and
>   $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ will have either $\text{Beta}$ or $\text{Uniform}$
>   priors, chosen by the user. For the $\text{Beta}$ priors, the mean and
>   variance will be specified. For the $\text{Uniform}$ priors, the upper
>   and lower limits will be specified.

My background is obviously not statistics, and I'm having a hard time patching gaps in my knowledge from the voluminous MCMC literature. Rather than burden commenters with explaining a mountain of Bayesian inference to me, **I'd appreciate it if people could point out the errors in my pseudocode and understanding, including instances in which I might be misusing terms**. I'll focus my study on those areas. I welcome suggested reading that is specific (I've seen but not completely read some of the suggestions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/mcmc-method-good-sources)).

I will be coding this by hand from scratch, except for simple maths functions.

Ultimately, I'll make sure there's complete and accurate pseudocode associated with this post.

**Proposed pseudocode**

> 1. Declare an initial value of $\theta_{0} = (N,p_{x},p_{y})$ and set equal to $\theta_{\text{current}}$.
> 2. Calculate the posterior probability of $\theta_{\text{current}}$:
>
>    - First, calculate the log-likelihood $\textit{L}_\text{current}$ of $\theta_{\text{current}}$. Here, the log-likelihood
>        $\textit{L}_\text{current}$ = $L_{x} + L_{y}$, where $L_{x}$ $=$
>        $\text{log}{N \choose X} + X$ $\text{log } p_{x} + (N-X) \text{ log }$
>        $(1-p_{x})$ and $L_{y}$ is analogous.
>    - Next, obtain the posterior by multiplying the likelihood $\exp\textit{L}_\text{current}$ by the prior,
>        $\text{Prior}(\theta_\text{current})$. The prior of
>        $\theta_\text{current}$ is the product of the priors of each of the
>        parameters in $\theta$. In this case, if the user has chosen
>        $\text{Beta}$ priors for $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$, the respective priors
>        are simply the $\text{Beta}$ pdf evaluated at $p_{x}$ or $p_{y}$. The
>        prior for $N$ is the pmf of the Poisson function at $N$.
> 3. Draw $\theta_{\text{candidate}}$ from the proposal distribution. **What exactly is this distribution for each parameter in $\theta$?** I've seen normal distributions used, but here  $N$ and $p_{x}$ clearly
>      must be drawn from different distributions.
> 4. Calculate the posterior of $\theta_{\text{candidate}}$ following step 2.
> 5. Evaluate whether to accept $\theta_{\text{candidate}}$ by comparing the posteriors, and update $\theta_{\text{current}}$ if
>      justified. I will use the Metropolis algorithm (not shown for
>      brevity).
> 6. Repeat steps 3-5 until convergence or reasonable stopping point.

**(tl;dr) Major questions**

- In step 2, am I missing shortcuts related to the conjugate priors? I still don't really understand what they're good for or if I'm calculating the prior correctly.
- How are jump distributions determined?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing I notice, though this might be a typo is: "The prior for $N$ is the pdf of the exponential function at $N$." Do you mean poisson? Also, as you assumed an exponential prior on $\lambda$, you need to add that as an additional variable.

Comment: Secondly, have you looked at Gibbs sampling? This is likely much easier for steps 3-5.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon: Quite right about the prior for $N$. Typo. Fixing. It's $\lambda$, not $N$, that's being estimated. I knew more about Gibbs sampling 4-5 y ago and can look into it again... but if there's a decent way to work from what's here, I'd like to try it first.

Comment: I commented too soon. It's not clear to me why both $N$ and $\lambda$ would be estimated (they're both the expected number of trials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Metropolis Hastings, then you don't have to worry too much about conjugacy of priors or finely-tuned proposal jumps.

- Conjugate priors are useful for avoiding or short-circuiting numerical computation. They shouldn't be necessary for running Metropolis Hastings on a simple model.
- For the proposal distribution, just try a random walk. If a proposal is outside the support of $\theta$, then reject it. (Think of it as having a prior value of zero.)

Also, there's a minor typo I think: you add the log prior to the log likelihood, or multiply the prior by the likelihood.